# How do you send api-key as authorization with http-kit in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, authorization, api-key, http-kit

I need to make an API call with `http-kit` in Clojure where it uses API-Key as authorization. That is, in Postman, you would usually have the option to add an `api-key`, `api-value` and the option to add it to `header` or `query-params`.

I know the following would be the way to go in case of `basic-auth`:

```
{:url "<api-url>"
 :method :post
 :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}
 :basic-auth [<username> <password>]
 :body <body>)}
```

But a similar variation isn't working with `api-key` version.
So far, I have tried:

```
{:basic-auth [<api-key> <api-value>]}
```

```
{:query-params {<api-key> <api-value>}}
```

```
{:query-params {:key <api-key>, :value <api-value>}}
```

```
{:headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"
           <api-key> <api-value>}
```

```
{:api-key [<api-key> <api-value>]}
```

```
{:api-key {<api-key> <api-value>}
```

and other variations, but it doesn't seem to be working.

(Note: The authorization works on postman but I couldn't test the full api call there because the body is too long and too complex to copy, and the authorization isn't working from the application.)

Comment: "But it doesn't seem to be working" - what errors do you get? what is the response? since you are wild-guessing with the api-key, and assuming that this is the actual proble: please also add what the documentation of your remote says about how to submit this.

Comment: @cfrick The api documentation says that the Authorization is done by api-key with the key-value pair. 
I get a `401` status with some of those combinations, and a type error resulting in Null Pointer Exception with the others.

Comment: But where is the other side looking for that? You have tried header and query-params. Is the endpoint you try to contact documented in the public, can you link it?

Comment: @cfrick Sure, here is the link to the documentation: 
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9780542/TVmHDetH#e4296d1e-58f4-4f6d-873f-04fd8a69c872

The demo doesn't have the api-key included in the request though, and it doesn't explicitly mention where it expects it either. 
(The content is in Spanish but Google Translate works fine).

Comment: Yeah, the documentation seems pretty useless.  My guess would be `{:headers {<key> "CONSULTAR"}}` then.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit a POST request in Postman with the API Key auth to a non-existent endpoint, the request will fail but you can still inspect the headers that were attempted in the request using the Console. I used placeholder values and the request headers looks like this:

```
MYAPIKEY: MYAPIVALUE
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 0494818d-5401-4baa-8ef7-bfce46c7196e
Host: localhost:5001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

This makes me think that with your request in http-kit needs at least a few of those headers (typically you'll need at least `Content-type`, `Accept` and your custom API key/value pair).

Comment: I changed the header to include the `Accept` value to be the following, but that didn't work either. 

`:headers {"Accept" "*/*",  "Content-Type" "application/json", <api-key>  <api-value>}`